# Can't Broadcast ethereum transaction, what's wrong with this transaction?

Tags: transactions, parity, raw-transaction

I used eth_sendTransaction with Parity to send some funds, but it does not seem to be getting mined.

The TX ID: `0x2b9d3c36d2cf2e56b5779f47c821791bdc6a0835b8b79c873bc221ff9e9e6a75`

The raw transaction: `0xf86d0b85052804393483030d4094f1c19dbd4a9cf2693f55704911fbcde5f40d15b8881bc16d674ec80000801ba00ed29289d190f617db636b97b1186a3d7b7495fa6529619e22146515acc4c5c0a02dadd44c7242549378750b49ee761e603f297de370703a6578f14a10e3a3aa7f`

I also have tried re-broadcasting the raw transaction here: https://etherscan.io/pushTx

Which seemed to work and give the same transaction ID, and then when re-attempting it gives the error: Transaction with the same hash was already imported.

So it seems that the transaction has been broadcast from both my node and from etherscan, but it isn't get confirmed?

I checked the gasprice which is the same as many other transactions being confirmed (0.000000022146201908 Ether) and the gas amount is sufficient.

Is there something wrong with this transaction?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem I found was that Parity had skipped a nonce, so that the next nonce was actually "0xa", but Parity decided to put "0xb" into the transaction.

To resolve this I created another transaction specifically adding nonce of "0xa"